# How to do Collapsing ToolBar Layout collapses with a button click?

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know if it's possible control when it collapses. Or if an effect similar can be done with an ImageView. I would like to do an effect similar to the app Yummly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AppBarLayout` has two methods that let you control the collapsing of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`: [`setExpanded(expanded, animate)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html#setExpanded(boolean,%20boolean)) and [`setExpanded(expanded)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html#setExpanded(boolean)). Call one of them inside your `OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 3):

Expand/Collapse `Toolbar` with a `FloatingActionButton` click using `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout`, `setExpanded(boolean expanded)` (Support Library v23+)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!--This view depends heavily on being used as a direct child within a CoordinatorLayout-->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#b71c1c"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:minHeight="96dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Expandable/Collapsible Toolbar" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/v2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24px"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/v2"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

appBarLayout.setExpanded(true/false)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final AppBarLayout appbarLayout = (AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.appbarLayout);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (appbarLayout.getTop() < 0)
                appbarLayout.setExpanded(true);
            else
                appbarLayout.setExpanded(false);
        }
    });
}
```

[Image: Expand/Collapse Toolbar with FAB click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gj0P.png)